# How to find the constant $c_0$ term in $ F(z) = \sum_{n=-Large1}^{Large2} {c_nz^{2n}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

How to determine if $c_0 = 0$ ?

Where

$$F(z) = \left(  \prod_{k = 0}^{N} (1+z^{2a_k}) \right) \left(  \prod_{j = 0}^{M} (z^{-2b_j} + z^{-2d_j}) \right)  = \sum_{n=-Large1}^{Large2} {c_nz^{2n}}$$

and $N,M,a_k,b_j,d_j \in \mathbb{N}$ and are known.

$N$ and $M$ are approximately $1000$ or larger.

$a_k$ and $b_j$ can be very large.

- Expanding both products would result in approximately $2^{N+M}$ terms and is intractable.
- Numerical quadrature around a  complex contour around $z = 0$ fails due to  high frequency oscillation caused by large $a_k$ ,$b_j$ and $d_j$.

---

Addendum Subset Sum problem

@mercio  identified the subset sum character of the problem.

Let $S = \{a_k\}$ , $a_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ be a set of integers.

Find a non empty subset of elements of $S$ that add to $0$.

A generating function for all the sums, excluding the empty set ($-1$) can be written as:

$$F(z) = -1 + \prod_{a_k \in S} (1+z^{a_k}) = \sum_{n} c_n z^n$$

If $c_0 \ne 0$ then a solution exists.

Each $a_k$ can be left out and $c_0$ redetermined to find a solution.

$$c_n = \frac1{2\pi i} \oint \frac{F(z)}{z^{n+1}} dz$$

---

Comment: Eric Wofsey - Yes. $F(z) = A(z)B(1/z)$ the problem originates from having two z transforms and trying to find where the powers of z match. So place 1/z as the argument of one z transform and see if there is a $c_0 \ne 0$

Comment: so isn't that the subset sum problem under disguise ? it's NP-complete.

Comment: mercio -  its related but with the right product you must pick one of a pair $b_j$ or $d_j$. With the left product the choice is $0$ or $a_k$. If there is a calculus approach to determine if $c_0 = 0$ then $b_j$ and $d_j$ can be removed individually and rerun the test to determine the solution.

Comment: mercio : $ z^{-2b_j} + z^{-2d_j} = z^{-2b_j}(1 + z^{-2(d_j-b_j)})$ by factoring out the right product it can be written as a subset sum. Thanks.